# for vs forEach issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

if for and forEach are both synchronous why does the forEach loop not work and always return false in this case? I keep thinkining it's too early in the morning and I have made a glaring error. Both cases say they found a match:

```
var items = [{
  Code: 'BLAH',
  ItemID: 'FOO'
}];

console.log(findItem('BLAH')); // FOO
console.log(findItem2('BLAH')); // false

function findItem(sku) {
  for(var i in items) {
    if(items[i].Code === sku) {
      console.log('Match found - for'):
      return items[i].ItemID;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function findItem2(sku) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.Code === sku) {
      console.log('Match found - forEach'):
      return item.ItemID;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It's because of function scope. The `for` loop has no special scope, so when you return inside it, you're returning from the outer function.
The `forEach` loop has a callback function with it's own scope, and returning from that does not return from the outer function, but from the callback only.

Comment: Lets simplify the issue: `function foo() { function bar() { return 21; } ; bar(); return 42; } ; foo();`. What do you expect `foo` to return when you call it?

Comment: Returning from a `forEach` function nested inside another function only returns from the inner `forEach` function.  It doesn't return from the outer function.  The `for` loop only has one function so a return anywhere returns from that outer function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` inside the callback you pass to `.forEach()` just terminates that function call, not the "findItem2" call. In other words, the `.forEach()` mechanism itself has called the function you've passed it, and your `return` statement just returns from that; the overall process continues. Nothing ever pays attention to the value you return.

This is a case where the plain `for` loop is probably a little clearer. Some function frameworks might offer something like `.forEach()` specialized for the task of locating the first element in a list that satisfies a given condition.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the downvote was for, but whatever.